# Bayesian AB Test Prior Distribution

Tags: probability, distributions, bayesian

I am trying to figure out the following issue - while using bayesian method for A/B testing and while comparing control to new variant (i know the control prior data but not the variant), can i use $Beta(a_1,b_1)$ with the historical data for the control ($a_1$ - success of control) and $Beta(1,1)$ for the variant since there is no prior knowledge of it? How it would impact the sampling the posterior distribution? Or should both priors (control and variants) should use the same prior?

thanks

Comment: Sorry, It is a bit unclear what your question is about. Could you elaborate a bit (for example what are your hypothesis, what is your model?)

Comment: Null Hypothesis is that there is no change between control conversion rate and variant conversion rate and im testing what is the probability that the variant cvr is "better" than the control's cvr. i've defined beta distribution as prior and binomial distribution based on observed conversion and beta dist. and im using markov chains for simulation based on the distributions i've mentioned before.